# Custom rectangle goes wrong on lower android version than 5.0

Tags: android, xml

I have created a custom xml like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:width="2dp"/>

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
<size
    android:height="400dp"
    android:width="1000dp" />
```

This is an empty rectangle with rounded corners. It looks well in 5.0+ android versions but when I tested it on 4.1 the rectangle filled in with black color.

Have you any idea what cause this?

Comment: There's a bug on older OS versions. You need to add a solid tag in your shape as well. I'm not sure if android:color/transparent will work on these older devices though...

Comment: Great answer thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to copy my previous comment: There's a bug on older OS versions. You need to add a solid tag in your shape as well. I'm not sure if android:color/transparent will work on these older devices though...